# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

**Error:**

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'
> while attempting to activate
> 'TestApp_03_RazorPage_Identity.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel'.
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
> sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

**detail**: I am following microsoft example, still it is not working when i try to set up a `ApplicationUser` class. I seen similar post and nothing is working for me

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = 
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
```

**ApplicationUser.cs**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
 {
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

**_LoginPartial.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

**RegisterModel**

```
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IUserStore<IdentityUser> _userStore;
    private readonly IUserEmailStore<IdentityUser> _emailStore;
    private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
```

Comment: From your question, you are using `scaffloded` to generate identity code and you are custom identity, But in `RegisterModel`, Why `T`  is still `identityUser` instead of `ApplicationUser` in  `IUserStore<T>` and `IUserEmailStore<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extends `IdentityUser`, you need to use `ApplicationUser`:

```
private readonly IUserStore<ApplicationUser> _userStore;
private readonly IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser> _emailStore;
```

instead of:

```
private readonly IUserStore<IdentityUser> _userStore;
private readonly IUserEmailStore<IdentityUser> _emailStore;
```

Comment: thanks, just getting an error on `IEmailSender` which doesnt have a <T>. do i need to change anything there? `InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender' while attempting to activate 'TestApp_04_RazorPage_Identity.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel`.

Comment: I think you need to extend `IEmailSender` too, [here is an example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eQYo8O) , and also need to add DI `builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();`